# Google Authentication Process

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to write a native app to access a users google calendar.  I am trying to use the example that google has provided to get authentication but it never seems to fire the authentication function

```
private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(
            GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
    provider.ClientIdentifier = "<My Client Id here>";
    provider.ClientSecret = "<My Client Secret here";

    var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(
        provider, (p) => GetAuthorization(provider));

    CalendarService service = new CalendarService();
    CalendarsResource.GetRequest cr = service.Calendars.Get("{primary}");

    if (cr.CalendarId != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fetching calendar");
        //Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Calendar c =
            service.Calendars.Get("{primary}").Fetch();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service not found");
    }
}
```

Here is the code that I am using for Authentication.  I never see the console writeline get published.

```
private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Authorization Requested");

    IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(
        new[] { CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue() });
    state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
    Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

    Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
    // Request authorization from the user and get the code
    string authCode = Console.ReadLine();

    // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
    return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
}
```

Are there any better tutorials available or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you able to solve this issue because i am facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The example code is broken. To make the service use your authenticator, you need to connect it. In the example there is no association between the service and the authenticator. Create the service like this:

```
var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    Authenticator = auth
};
```

Look at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/ for better documentation/working code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new [docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate). You'll need to replace

```cs
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(
    provider, (p) => GetAuthorization(provider));
```

with

```cs
AuthenticatorFactory.GetInstance().RegisterAuthenticator(
    () => new OAuth2Authenticator(provider, GetAuthentication));
```

As the comment says, when you call `var service = new CalendarService()`, the previously registered authenticator will automatically be called.

Comment: What references need to be added to use this? When ever I add this piece of code in visual studio says it can't find the factory and there is no resolve action for it either.

Comment: As in the sample, `using System; using System.Diagnostics; using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2; using Google.Apis.Authentication; using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2; using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth; using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3; using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data; using Google.Apis.Util;`

You can download the DLL at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Calendar_API

Answer (score 0):

I think the above ways are related to old version of Google calendar DLL. Does any one know about the documentation of new version of Google calendar i.e. V 1.8.1.82. Google never provides the good documentation for .NET developer.s