# NativeApplicationClient.ClientIdentifier is not resolving

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, dotnetopenauth, google-analytics-api

I have already referred to this post **[Google Authentication Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792187/google-authentication-process)**, which is not exactly similar to my issue but the code I am using is similar.

```
using System;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Samples.Helper;

private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
     provider.ClientIdentifier = "<My Client Id here>";
     provider.ClientSecret = "<My Client Secret here";
     ...
     ...
}
```

My problem is neither `provider.ClientIdentifier` nor `provider.Secret` is getting resolved. I am referencing to DotNetOpenAuth version 4.0.0.11165 and Google API version v201306.

My object is to fetch Google Analytic data from different accounts, but before that I need the user to be authenticated and Google can allow him offline access by providing an Access_Token!

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Regards,
Subrata

Answer (score 0):

What type of application are you building (Web, Service Account, Installed Application)?    The way you get the oath token changes depending on what type of application it is.